# do something if attribute value is singular

Tags: xml, xslt, attributes

I have a large XML-File where persons are attributed with an identifying value. A simplified version would be:

```
<start>
<text 1>
    <person key="A00001">Adam Ant</person>
    <person key="A00001">Mr. A.</person>
</text 1>
<text 2>
   <poem>
    <person key="A00002">Mrs. Bee</person>
    <person key="A00003">Cecily</person>
    <person key="A00001">A.</person>
   </poem>
</text 2>
</start>
```

I try to single out those persons where the value-key exits only once in the whole document. I guess the solutions has to do with generate-id(.) but I'm not sure. How could I use XSLT to have A00002 and A00003 as output?

(xslt 2.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a key `<xsl:key name="group" match="person/@key" use="."/>` and then compute `distinct-values(//person/@key)[not(key('group', .)[2])]` only you need to store the root, as in

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:key name="group" match="person/@key" use="."/> 

    <xsl:variable name="root" select="/"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="distinct-values(//person/@key)[not(key('group', ., $root)[2])]"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As an alternative you could of course use `<xsl:for-each-group select="//person/@key" group-by="."><xsl:if test="not(current-group()[2])"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:if></xsl:for-each>`.